# SQL Query via Excel not working

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I want to upload my list box in Excel with data from SQL server.

I'm running this query on server and is working fine.

I tried to search for help on google but failed.

I have an problem with my query syntax I assume.

```
s = "SELECT DISTINCT(B.[Manager Name]), A.[SESA ID] " & _
"FROM [Current Job Data] AS A" & _
"LEFT JOIN [Work Relationship Report] AS B " & _
"ON B.[Manager Person Number]= A.[Employee Person Number] " & _
"INNER JOIN [Work Relationship Report] AS C ON  B.[Manager Name] = C.[Manager Name]" & _
"WHERE b.[Manager Name] Is Not Null"
```

When I run my query I'm getting an error message:

> The multi-part identifier "A.Employee Person Number" could not be
>   bound.

I don't know how to fix this, thank you for your help :)

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function (on a column), it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`, and applies to the whole selected rows. Remove those redundant parentheses and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT B.[Manager Name]) + ...` to make things clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add trailing spaces. Your whole string is a one line string.

```
FROM [Current Job Data] AS A" & _ "LEFT Join..."
```

becomes

```
FROM [Current Job Data] AS ALEFT Join ...
```

Thus there is no identifier `A`

Comment: Thank you ! I'm blind :)